# How to force downgrade a transitive dependency's patch version?

Tags: rust-cargo

Suppose my project depends on library A v1.0.0, which depends on library B v2.0.0. The author of B releases a new v2.0.1, which is picked up by A v1.0.1. Unfortunately, B v2.0.1 introduces a bug that affects small amount of users, me as being one of them. Even though I report the issue to B, it takes time for them to fix, not to mention with low priority due to low impact.

Because this is transitive dependency, I can't fix my own Cargo.toml to force a downgrade.

I can downgrade my dependency to A to v1.0.0, but v1.0.1 contains new functionality I need, and downgrading B only affects A features I don't use anyway.

I know I can use [`[patch]` section](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/overriding-dependencies.html#the-patch-section) to fix any dependency, but that mysteriously requires the source to be different, so I have to git clone library A locally and change their Cargo.toml, or clone library B locally and fix the bug myself. Both options are tedious and maintenance heavy.

Is there any other solution? Why does Cargo not allow the `[patch]` section to just specify a lower version, like

```
[patch.crates-io]
B = '=2.0.0'
```